# Imagemagik with php

Tags: php, imagemagick

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'ImagickDrawException' with message
> 'The given font is not found in the
> ImageMagick configuration and the file
> (/var/www/Arial) is not accessible' in
> /var/www/captcha.php:20 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/captcha.php(20): ImagickDraw->setfont('Arial') #1
>
> {main} thrown in /var/www/captcha.php
> on line 20

I am getting the following errors when i try the following

```
<?php

/* Create Imagick object */
$Imagick = new Imagick();



/* Set font and font size. You can also specify /path/to/font.ttf */
$ImagickDraw->setFont( 'Helvetica Regular' );


?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a filename to `setFont()`, not a font name. E.g:

```
ImagickDraw->setFont('fonts/arial.ttf');
```

See the comment on [the PHP manual page](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-setfont.php). Apparently this function only accepts filenames relative to the site root. It does not accept font names like `Imagick::setFont()` does.